Bedeutungen von "aussetzen"
Basierend auf den Gegenwartskorpora von DWDS und context.reverso.net weiß ich sicher, dass das Verb aussetzen häufig im Sinne von exponieren (Beispiele: jmdn. einer Gefahr aussetzen, der glühenden Sonne ausgesetzt sein usw.) und auf- oder hinausschieben verwendet wird. Sowohl der Duden als auch das DWDS listen viele weitere Bedeutungen auf: Neben dem offensichtlichen hinaussetzen auch als Belohnung oder Äquivalent für eine Leistung festsetzen (eine Definition des DWDS, die sich leicht von der des Dudens — in Aussicht stellen, versprechen — unterscheidet, da ein Beispiel des Dudens wie jmdm. ein Erbteil aussetzen dies nicht abdeckt), (vorübergehend, unerwartet) aufhören und weitere. Während einer relativ kurzen Recherche in den Gegenwartskorpora habe ich das Verb hauptsächlich im Sinne von exponieren, auf- oder hinausschieben sowie vorübergehend unterbrechen verwendet gesehen (wobei Letzteres von Duden als seltener gekennzeichnet ist, während DWDS dies nicht angibt).
Ich verstehe, dass die Korpora nur bestimmte Sprachstile einschließen. Deshalb frage ich hier: Sind Ausdrücke wie er setzt dafür eine Belohnung von 1000 € aus und der Motor hat ausgesetzt noch gebräuchlich, insbesondere in Norddeutschland? Und wird einen Streik aussetzen wirklich nicht so oft wie die anderen Bedeutungen verwendet?

Die Beispiele für die Belohnung und den Motor klingen ganz natürlich. Auch "Streik aussetzen" ist nicht Ungeföhnlich. Was ich nicht verstehe, ist die Anwendung im Sinn von "to expose" (preisgeben). Hast Du dafür ein konkretes Beispiel gefunden?

@user1934428 Danke schön! Ich meine Sätze wie "jmdn. einer Gefahr aussetzen", "der glühenden Sonne ausgesetzt sein" usw.

Ah, jetzt ist es klar.

Das Verb aussetzen hat viele Bedeutungen:

verstoßen

In der Urlaubszeit gibt es immer wieder Menschen, die ihre Haustiere an Autobahnrastplätzen aussetzen.


Aus der Obhut entlassen

Nachdem sich die Kaulquappen in der Aufzuchtstation zu Fröschen entwickelt haben, wird man die Tiere im nahegelegenen Augebiet aussetzen.


eine Zeit lang nicht teilnehmen

Ich bin schon müde und möchte bei diesem Spiel mal ein oder zwei Runden lang aussetzen.


exponieren

Man draf die Freiwilligen bei den Aufräumarbeiten keiner gefährlichen Strahlung aussetzen.


Eine Belohnung festlegen

Wenn wir für die besten Teilnehmer Preise aussetzen, erhöht das die Motivation.


kritisieren

Du hast anscheinend auch an allem etwas auszusetzen.




Als Österreicher kann ich über den Gebrauch in Norddeutschland keine Aussagen machen, aber vielleicht hilft es auch, etwas über den Gebrauch im Süden zu erfahren:

Er setzt dafür eine Belohnung von 1000 € aus.
Diese Formulierung ist in Österreich gängig, und wird meinen Recherchen nach auch im gesamten deutschen Sprachraum verwendet. Alternative Verben sind festsetzen, festlegen, ausloben.

Der Motor hat ausgesetzt
Auch sehr gängig. Im Moment fällt mir kein anderes Verb, das ich in diesem Kontext verwenden würde.

Einen Streik aussetzen
Das ist deswegen weniger gebräuchlich, weil der Vorgang selbst selten stattfindet. Wenn aber ein Streik unterbrochen oder ganz abgesagt wird, spricht nichts dagegen, dafür das Verb aussetzen zu verwenden.



An der Liste der Beispiele ist auch aus meiner norddeutschen Sicht nichts auszusetzen; die sind auch alle hier gebräuchlich.

Danke Ihnen herzlich für eine detaillierte Antwort!
